# Disk full on Azure or what?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I get this exception (from a plugin) in the logs of the web app:

**System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.**

This is when calling new System.IO.FileStream(...).

I've verified that there are plenty of space on app disk and on the temp disk, so what else disk can be full?

Comment: What application?  Or more detail from the failure?  Maybe you're misconfigured and not writing to the disk you intend?  Or a volume you don't have quota on?

Comment: I know this is a little but vague, but I dont have direct access to the azure env and are out of ideas and desperate, so just hoping for someone to have something that I can investigate further :)
According to the support that does have access to the Azure env, it's not the web app disk space nor the temp disk space or quota. SO what else can give out of disk space on azure ?!